# Need help to optimize the My SQL query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I need help on optimizing the following query

```
select 
  DATE_FORMAT( traffic.stat_date, '%Y/%m'),
  pt.promotion,
  sum(traffic.voice_nat_onnet_mins - pt.promo_minutes_onnet) as total_onnet_mins,
  sum(traffic.voice_nat_offnet_mins + traffic.voice_nat_landline_mins + traffic.voice_int_mins + traffic.voice_nng_mins + traffic.voice_not_rec_mins - pt.promo_minutes_offnet) as total_offnet_mins,
  sum(traffic.sms_ptp_onnet_evts) as total_onnet_sms,
  sum(traffic.sms_ptp_offnet_evts + traffic.sms_vas_pta_evts) as total_offnet_sms,
  sum(traffic.dati_kb) as internet_kb
from 
  stats_novercanet.mnp_prod_stat_outgoing_traffic traffic
  INNER JOIN stats_novercanet.mnp_prod_stat_promotion_traffic pt 
    ON pt.id_source_user=traffic.id_source_user
  INNER JOIN stats_novercanet.mnp_prod_stat_customer_first_signup fs
    ON pt.id_source_user = fs.id_source_user
where
  traffic.stat_date between '2013-11-01' and '2013-11-30'
  and traffic.stat_date >= (
    select min(ft.stat_date)
    from stats_novercanet.mnp_prod_stat_promotion_traffic ft
    where 
      traffic.id_source_user=ft.id_source_user 
      and (ft.sub_rev>0 or ft.ren_rev>0)
      and pt.promotion=ft.promotion
  )
  and pt.stat_date  between '2013-11-01' and '2013-11-30'
group by
  DATE_FORMAT( traffic.stat_date, '%Y/%m'),
  pt.promotion
order by
  DATE_FORMAT( traffic.stat_date, '%Y/%m'),
  pt.promotion **
```

I have used explain for this query and it showed me following result

```
+----+--------------------+---------+-------+------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table   | type  | possible_keys                                  | key                             | key_len | ref                                     | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+---------+-------+------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | pt      | range | idx_prod_stat_pro_tra_stat_date,id_source_user | idx_prod_stat_pro_tra_stat_date | 4       | NULL                                    | 530114 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | fs      | ref   | id_source_user                                 | id_source_user                  | 5       | stats_novercanet.pt.id_source_user      |      1 | Using where; Using index                     |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | traffic | ref   | stat_date,id_source_user                       | id_source_user                  | 5       | stats_novercanet.pt.id_source_user      |     60 | Using where                                  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ft      | ref   | id_source_user,promotion                       | id_source_user                  | 5       | stats_novercanet.traffic.id_source_user |     93 | Using where                                  |
+----+--------------------+---------+-------+------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Any help on optimization will be great. I have created index on id_source_user, stat_date and promotion as well but no luck. Also tried with subquery in join but no luck.

Result is as follow for mnp_prod_stat_promotion_traffic.****

```
| mnp_prod_stat_promotion_traffic | CREATE TABLE `mnp_prod_stat_promotion_traffic` (
  `stat_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_source_user` int(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `promotion` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num_of_sub` int(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num_of_ren` int(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `credit` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `minutes` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `kb` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `sms` int(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lbs` int(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sub_rev` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `ren_rev` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `consumed_credit` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `sim_type` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_plan` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WiFi_mins` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `over_min` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `over_min_consumed` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `over_sms` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `over_sms_consumed` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `over_data` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `over_data_consumed` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `promo_minutes_onnet` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `promo_minutes_offnet` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `promo_sms_onnet` int(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `promo_sms_offnet` int(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `idx_prod_stat_pro_tra_stat_date` (`stat_date`),
  KEY `id_source_user` (`id_source_user`),
  KEY `promotion` (`promotion`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Comment: Please post the result of `show create table stats_novercanet.mnp_prod_stat_promotion_traffic;`

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com ASAP.

Comment: I have added the result of show create table stats_novercanet.mnp_prod_stat_promotion_traffic; in question. And result of explain query is also there in question itself. I forgot to write that I need to join mnp_prod_stat_customer_first_signup table which is there in query to use where condition of overall result. But if filter is not selected that where condition will not be there.

Answer (score 0):

How many results are you expecting to get returned. If you know for example that you only want one record returned then you can use LIMITS

When a query is ran it will search the whole table for that record, but if you know the is only one, two or three results returned then you can LIMIT. This will save MySQL a lot of time, but again it will depend on the number of results you are excepting, and you will have to apply it to the tables you are running it on.

Also, another tip is to check what type of table types you are using. Have a look at this webpage for more information: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/understand-mysql-table-types-innodb-myisam.aspx

Another option to do is to build a script to use your existing query above and store the result in a new table, and only run the script once a month via cron at like midnight. I did this for an analytical project, and it worked well.

Comment: I want all the result for that month. I can't use limit. Also it is using MyISAM  data engine

Comment: I added another suggestion at the bottom of my answer about using a script and table. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Cameron I may use script and table but again just for one day also it is taking too long to run and daily script should be updated for one month so script will run forever it seems.